# Joining two tables in mysql by selecting one colum twice from one table

Tags: mysql

I have a database with the folliwing column

```
sender_account_id     receiver_account_id   date
123                   234                   2013-01-23
124                   235                   2012-04-04
```

And another table having the following column

```
account_id           rank
123                  4
124                  5
234                  1
235                  7
```

What i want is to get the following results

```
sender_account_id   rank   receiver_account_id    rank
123                 4      234                    1
124                 5      235                    7
```

Please any help....

The query i tried is

```
SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT kudosent.sender_account_id, account.kudo_rank
FROM kudosent
INNER JOIN account ON kudosent.sender_account_id = account.account_id
WHERE kudosent.sender_account_id =337
) AS A
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT kudosent.sender_account_id AS b1id, kudosent.receiver_account_id, account.kudo_rank
FROM kudosent
INNER JOIN account ON kudosent.receiver_account_id = account.account_id
WHERE kudosent.sender_account_id =337
) AS B ON A.sender_account_id = B.B1id
UNION (

SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT kudosent.sender_account_id, account.kudo_rank
FROM kudosent
INNER JOIN account ON kudosent.sender_account_id = account.account_id
WHERE kudosent.sender_account_id =337
) AS A
RIGHT JOIN (

SELECT kudosent.sender_account_id AS B2id, kudosent.receiver_account_id, account.kudo_rank
FROM kudosent
INNER JOIN account ON kudosent.receiver_account_id = account.account_id
WHERE kudosent.sender_account_id =337
) AS B ON A.sender_account_id = B.B2id
)
```

it works well with where clauses but if i remove them the query runs forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use JOIN the another table 2 times something as

```
select 
t1.sender_account_id,
t2.rank as sender_rank,
t1.receiver_account_id,
t3.rank as receiver_rank 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.sender_account_id = t2.account_id 
join table2 t3 on t1.receiver_account_id = t3.account_id
```

Here is a **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b91f/1)**

Change the table names in the query as per your table name and it should work.

**UPDATE**
The following query should do the trick, your query is pretty messed up

```
select 
t1.sender_account_id,
t2.rank as sender_rank,
t1.receiver_account_id,
t3.rank as receiver_rank 
from kudosent t1
join account t2 on t1.sender_account_id = t2.account_id 
join account t3 on t1.receiver_account_id = t3.account_id
```

Comment: I have only two tables not three and when i tried this i got this error #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'account' which account is the second table with only account_id and rank.Please help

Comment: update the question and add the query that you tried.

Comment: what is the table name of the first table ?

Comment: The queries i tried are so long and without where clause it causes the query to run forever.

Comment: what is the first table name ?

Comment: I put the query on question the first table is kudosent and the second table is account

Comment: check my update, try the 2nd query and it will work. Here how it works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7213b/1

Comment: Its works thank you but it comes with duplicates i fix by adding DISTINCT on sender_account_id. But still works with where clause if i just run without where clause it runs forever.